# jQuery two backslashes Safari 8.0 bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, safari, osx-yosemite

I'm on Mac OS 10.10 Yosemite, Safari 8.0.

I try to read an XML (RSS) file :

```
<content:encoded>bla bla bla</content:encoded>
```

My Js-Ajax is like :

```
description:$(valeur).find('content\\:encoded').text()
```

An alert of "description" is empty.

It seems there is a problem with the double backslash which are not escaping my double point. Is it a Safari 8 bug ?

Thanks,
Julien

Comment: Since you suspect a browser bug, does that mean you have tried it with other browsers and it works correctly with them?

Comment: And what is `valeur` then on Safari 8?

Comment: Yes it works with firefox 33.0.2.

I'm sorry `valeur` is just a parameter (my doc). I'm sure the problem is not here.

Comment: I try on safari7.1,and it work's fine:) Anyone can help to test safari 8?

Comment: `$(valeur).find(...)` So `valeur` could really be related to your issue. Is it expected value on Safari 8 for `valeur`? Are you sure this is an escaping issue?

Comment: I'm sure valeur is not the problem.   

 `$(valeur).find(...) ` works with other dom element. And i'm sure there is a `content:encoded` element in my doc

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and used

```
$('#' + id.replace(/:/g, '\\:'))
```

Comment: my find is on a element, not an id.

Comment: Ok, then you might try `'content:encoded'.replace(/:/g, '\\:')` which can be a difference in such a behaviour.

Comment: `'content:encoded'.replace(/:/g, '\\:')` is *exactly* the same as `'content\\:encoded'`.

Comment: Not quite. For humans yes, but sometimes it avoids some parser problems because the character replacement ist done during runtime processes. It is hard to explain but I had a similar problem where this trick was a success.

Comment: If your content was in a variable it was different because you weren't sure what the variable actually contained, but please do show a situation where `'content:encoded'.replace(/:/g, '\\:')` will behave differently than `'content\\:encoded'`.

Comment: You are right by definition. Both examples contain the same string. I have been digging for my example but it is inside a variable. So this is your point. My thoughts in first place were of a parser/interpreter problem of the browser. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: I'm agree with your idea.
I've try `var myString = 'content:encoded'.replace(/:/g, '\\:');`
then `description:$(valeur).find(myString).text()`
But it's still not working.